# How to turn off the highlighting of folded code in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Today, something has changed in my VSCode. Can anyone help me with this?

Does anybody know how to turn off the highlighting of folded code in VSCode like in the example screenshot?

[image: VSCode Screenshot]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

File -> Preferences -> Settings

Then search for 'Folding highlight' and uncheck the box. That will turn off the highlight.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can also change the color and/or opacity of the folded highlight with this `colorCustomization` in your `settings.json`:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

   // last two digits `aa` in this case below are opacity
  "editor.foldBackground": "#ff0000aa"
}
```